# Tensorflow - why do all the elements in my array of tensors end up eval-ing into the exact same result?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to create a 10x3 tensor out of ten 1x3 tensors. This is my attempt to do so:

```
import tensorflow as tf

g = tf.Graph()
res = []
with g.as_default():
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    dr1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], minval=1, maxval=7, dtype=tf.int32, seed=0))
    dr2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], minval=1, maxval=7, dtype=tf.int32, seed=1))
    rowres = tf.add(dr1, dr2)
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    for i in range(5):
      sess.run(init)
      row = tf.concat([dr1, dr2, rowres], 0)
      res.append(row)
      res_tsr = tf.stack(res)
      print(res_tsr.eval())
```

My problem is that, with this setup, when I evaluate the resulting stacked tensor in `res_tsr`, every single tensor seems to be the same:

```
first loop    [[4 4 8]]
second loop   [[4 4 8] [4 4 8]]
third loop    [[2 3 5] [2 3 5] [2 3 5]]
fourth loop   [[4 1 5] [4 1 5] [4 1 5] [4 1 5]]
fifth loop    [[3 6 9] [3 6 9] [3 6 9] [3 6 9] [3 6 9]]
expected      [[4 4 8] [4 4 8] [2 3 5] [4 1 5] [3 6 9]]
```

All of them take the values of the last tensor added to the list.

What I expected is to have each tensor to evaluate differently like in the `expected` row. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're appending Tensor objects to `res`, whereas you should be appending whatever they evaluate to (i.e., append `sess.run(row)`, not `row`).

Some unsolicited feedback on your code: each iteration of your for loop adds two nodes to the graph (a `concat` node and a `stack` node); adding nodes to graphs in an evaluation loop is considered bad practice, as it quickly leads to extremely large graphs. As a rule of thumb, any for loop that runs a session should not modify the graph that's being executed. The following code snippet adheres to this rule of thumb while still accomplishing your particular goal.

```
import tensorflow as tf

g = tf.Graph()
res = []
with g.as_default():
  dr1 = tf.random_uniform([1], minval=1, maxval=7, dtype=tf.int32, seed=0)
  dr2 = tf.random_uniform([1], minval=1, maxval=7, dtype=tf.int32, seed=1)
  rowres = tf.add(dr1, dr2)
  row = tf.concat([dr1, dr2, rowres], axis=0)

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(5):
      print("Loop ", i)
      res.append(sess.run(row))
      print(res)
```

Executing the  above snippet yields the following output:

```
Loop  0
[array([4, 4, 8], dtype=int32)]
Loop  1
[array([4, 4, 8], dtype=int32), array([4, 4, 8], dtype=int32)]
Loop  2
[array([4, 4, 8], dtype=int32), array([4, 4, 8], dtype=int32), array([2, 3, 5], dtype=int32)]
Loop  3
[array([4, 4, 8], dtype=int32), array([4, 4, 8], dtype=int32), array([2, 3, 5], dtype=int32), array([4, 1, 5], dtype=int32)]
Loop  4
[array([4, 4, 8], dtype=int32), array([4, 4, 8], dtype=int32), array([2, 3, 5], dtype=int32), array([4, 1, 5], dtype=int32), array([3, 6, 9], dtype=int32)]
```

Comment: Oh yeah. I forgot about the evaluation part. Thanks for that.

Comment: Glad to help! Do you mind accepting this answer, if possible, to mark the question as answered?